# Need to sync data between two tables from different servers Postgresql databases

Tags: c#, postgresql, synchronization, database-migration, change-tracking

I have two postgresql databases (prod and stats) running on two different servers. I need to copy records between two tables from these databases. I need to do this 1-2 times a day. It is like a syncing, but after copy data from prod.table1 to stats.table1, i need to update some information in stats.table1 (set additional data in stats.table1 columns and etc.). So, full backup/restore is a bad option for me(my additional data will be lost).
I heard about dblink/postgres_fdw, but i don't know how i can tracking my records in prod db.
Maybe i need to develop app for this?

Can you help me with my problem and give me some examples?

Comment: "but i don't know how i can tracking my records in prod db"  By there primary key?

Comment: Sorry, i forget write, My primary key is UUID

Answer (score 0):

You could use logical replication to sync data to stats db. You could have extra columns/table on stats db. Once data is pushed to stats server you could summarize and populate reports on stats db.

check below link to learn more about logical replication.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/logical-replication-postgresql-explained